# Webservice CAS-Authentication from C# Desktop application

Tags: c#, web-services, cas

we are writing a wpf-desktop application using a webservice to receive data from another tool (RPlan). The webservice uses CAS to authorize users. How can I do this in a desktop application? I 've only found samples for asp.net.

Description for CAS:
http://www.jasig.org/cas

Can someone help us out?

Thanks Tobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAS is really a web-oriented SSO with cookies, HTTP 302 redirects...
In your case, I understand that you want to present a login screen inside your WPF application and then send the "CAS authentication" to the needed web service. As I think that you don't want to use an embedded browser, you can use an extension to CAS which allows to authenticate (ticket granting ticket concept) and gain access (service ticket concept) to a service (your web service) using REST requests : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API.
Best regards,
Jérôme

Comment: How would you generate or provide a cookie for SSO? I means using this you might not get SSO fucntionality. If yes then Is there any way to provide your own screen for authetication against CAS and also enable SSO (means generate/provide cookies)?